# functional non-tail recursive version of selection sort in Haskell

Tags: haskell, selection-sort

I am looking for the non-tail recursive version of the following [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) code in Haskell:

```
import Data.List (minimum, delete)

ssort :: Ord t => [t] -> [t]
ssort [] = []
ssort xs = let { x = minimum xs } in  x : ssort (delete x xs)
```

Can you please provide with a non-tail recursive version of selection sort?

I know it is not a good idea to change the original code but I need that version to proceed with an experiment.

Comment: Is this version tail-recursive? This does not look like a tail-recursive function, since you emit `(:) x (ssort (delete x xs))`, so `ssort` is not the "outer" function. This looks like ["tail recursion *modulo cons*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons).

Comment: Haskell doesn't use (or need) tail-call optimization because of its lazy evaluation model.

Comment: (Which means there's usually little reason to go out of your way to make a function tail-recursive.)

Comment: thanks for your feedback, the code is meant for an experiment in a prover system.

Comment: @chepner, I think that's somewhat misleading. Haskell very often *does* need functions to be written in a tail-recursive fashion. It just needs it in fewer cases than an eager language would. Any time you choose `foldl'` over a similar `foldr` it is (or should be) because the problem demands tail recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code presented is not tail-recursive since you invoke the `:` cons function. All the recursive calls will be held on the memory stack waiting for the evaluation of `ssort (delete x xs)` to finish. A tail-recursive version could look like this:

```
import Data.List (minimum, delete)

ssort :: Ord t => [t] -> [t] -> [t]
ssort [] acc = reverse acc
ssort xs acc = let { x = minimum xs } in ssort (delete x xs) (x : acc)
```

Comment: This sorts in reverse: `ssort [3,1,2] = [3,2,1]`. (Replace `minimum` with `maximum` to fix, because you are prepending an element to the result *before* making your recursive call now, rather than after.) The non-tail-recursive version isn't quite as bad as you make it out. Because of laziness, there's only ever one delayed call to `ssort` sitting in memory; you only need to evaluate that call to get the next item in the result, at which point the *next* delayed recursive call replaces the former.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there anyway It can be sorted in increasing order, for example [1,2,3] instead of [3,2,1]. I think this change might work "append  acc x" instead of "(x : acc)" but not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: @PierreContreras Using `acc ++ [x]` would work, but would defeat the purpose of the tail-recursive call, as now you would just be piling up unevaluated calls to `++` (as well as make the traversal of the result an O(n^2) operation instead of an O(n) operation).

Comment: You're right that the code is not tail recursive, but it doesn't wait for the recursive call to finish before applying the `(:)` constructor.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**: the code is **not tail-recursive**.

> Can you please provide with a non-tail recursive version of selection sort?

The code is *not* tail recursive. It is ["*tail recursive modulo cons*" [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons), but not tail recursive.

The [Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tail_recursion) shows how to find out if a function is tail-recursive:

> Here is formal definition of "tail recursive". "`f` occurs in `t`"
>   means `f` is a free variable of `t`.
>
> When a function is defined (in let or at the top level) as:
>
> ```
> f = t
> ```
>
> where `f` is a name and `t` is a lambda-term, `f` is tail recursive
>   iff `f` occurs tail recursively in `t`. `f` occurs tail recursively in
>   `t` iff `f` occurs in `t` and any of the following holds:
>
> - `t` is variable;
> - `t` is `\var -> t0` and f occurs tail recursively in `t0`;
> - `t` is `t0 t1` and f occurs tail recursively in `t0` and does not occur in `t1`;
> - `t` is `let bs in t0` and `f` occurs tail recursively in `t0` and for each binder `var = t1` in `bs`, `f` does not occur in `t1`;
> - `t` is `case t0 of bs` and `f` does not occur in `t0` and for each branch `b` in `bs`, `f` does not
>     occur or occurs tail recursively in `b`;
>
>   - when we are saying "occur in
>       `b`", `b` has form `D vars -> t1` (where `D` is some data constructor and
>       `vars` is a sequence of names), we are thinking of the
>       lambda-abstraction `\vars -> t1` instead of `b`.

The expression `t` is `\xs -> let x = minimum xs in  x : ssort (delete x xs)`, so we can take the second item here, but then `ssort` needs to be tail-recursive in the `let ... in ...` statement, this is the fourth case.

But this fourth case requires that that `ssort` is tail recursive in the "body" of the `let ... in ...` expression. This expression is `((:) x) (ssort delete xs)`. This is thus the third case.

In the third case, the expression is of shape `t0 t1`, here with `t0 = (:) x` and `t1 = ssort delete xs`. Since `ssort` does not occur in `t0`, there is no tail recursion here.